# U-Net image size for training

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-processing

I have a small question regarding the size of images used for training the U-Net. I have thus far been able to train a U-Net reasonably well using 656x656 images and now wanted to use sections of 160x160 size for training. When using these small sections for training, the training accuracy increases in a similar fashion as with the large images but the validation accuracy seems to be much lower after each epoch. Furthermore it stops increasing after only a few epochs. The network includes dropout layers and I have also tried it with batchnorm and for the large images both approaches work but for the small sections nothing does. Can anybody point out to me what I am missing?

Comment: If you're taking crops of 160x160 from a 656x656 image then it's possible that you're making it too hard for the network to do whatever it's supposed to do.

Comment: @shimao has a good point. I just want to add that since you decreased size of the input you have to decrease capacity of the network in order to avoid overfitting. It's easier for network to memorize 160x160 images, compare to 656x656 images (even if you use dropout and batchnorm it's still can be an issue)